# How to plot Stacked Bar Chart with Text Overlay with Plotly in Python?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a **Stacked Bar Chart with Text Overlay** with Plotly in Python. Like the below one

[image]

**Sample Data**

| Fail_Word | Fail_Count | Pass_Word | Pass_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| properly | 48 | michigan | 9 |
| fraudulent | 64 | bodily | 39 |
| train | 41 | unauthorized | 28 |
| eos | 42 | insufficient | 28 |
| inaccurate | 42 | decision | 8 |
| strategy | 41 | program | 18 |
| escalate | 14 | inability | 96 |
| report | 124 | actuarial | 128 |
| register | 14 | account | 86 |
| applicable | 42 | annual | 88 |

I have tried the below code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=["Fail"],
    x=word_tr["Fail_Count"].to_list(),
    name="Fail",
    orientation='h',
    
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=["Pass"],
    x=word_tr["Pass_Count"].to_list(),
    name="Pass",
    orientation='h',
    
))

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image]

For `Fail` bar, I want to add `Fail_Word` and `Fail_Count` as stacked bar, similarly for `Pass` ---> `Pass_Word` and `Pass_Count`.

But could not be able to generate the required **Stacked Bar Chart with Text Overlay** plot. Can someone shed some light on how to plot a **Stacked Bar Chart with Text Overlay** in plotly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- primarily this is restructuring dataframe so that it is well structured for **Plotly Express**

| index | level_1 | Count | Word | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Fail | 124 | report | 0.262712 |
| 1 | Fail | 64 | fraudulent | 0.135593 |
| 0 | Fail | 48 | properly | 0.101695 |
| 3 | Fail | 42 | eos | 0.0889831 |
| 4 | Fail | 42 | inaccurate | 0.0889831 |

- then define **x**, **y**, **color** and **text**
- finally update **texttemplate**
- have excluded small contributors as there is insufficient space in figure to show text

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """Fail_Word,Fail_Count,Pass_Word,Pass_Count
properly,48,michigan,9
fraudulent,64,bodily,39
train,41,unauthorized,28
eos,42,insufficient,28
inaccurate,42,decision,8
strategy,41,program,18
escalate,14,inability,96
report,124,actuarial,128
register,14,account,86
applicable,42,annual,88"""
    )
)

# restructure dataframe for plotting
df2 = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df.reset_index(),
        stubnames=["Fail", "Pass"],
        i="index",
        j="data",
        sep="_",
        suffix="\\w+",
    )
    .stack()
    .unstack(1)
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(["level_1", "Count"], ascending=[1, 0])
    .groupby("level_1", as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda d: d.assign(Percent=d["Count"] / d["Count"].sum()))
)

fig = px.bar(
    df2.loc[df2["Percent"].gt(0.05)],
    y="level_1",
    x="Percent",
    color="level_1",
    orientation="h",
    text="Word",
)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate="%{text}<br>%{x:.1%}")
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title="", legend_title="", xaxis_tickformat=".0%")
```

[image]